# Which javascript command/library creates a dialog with the close button outside the border?

Tags: javascript, user-interface

See the picture.

[image]

I don't think it is jQuery since jQuery.ui dialog looks different.

Comment: any one of thousands of them.

Comment: Try fancybox: http://fancybox.net/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/blog) can do this for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
        {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );
});
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mh9nB/

Comment: Too bad it's not quite free.